# Counting quotes and formatting source code

Tags: formatting, lua, code-formatting, double-quotes

I'm doing some basic formatting for my Lua code. Like adding missing whitespace around math operands etc.

Now I realized it's a really bad idea to do these formattings if I'm inbetween quotation marks (ie. I don't want to alter strings in the code).

What would be the most elegent way around this problem. My ideas so far:

- Do a regexp as I've done so far to find a place I want to edit and then count quotation marks from the beginning of the string to this place. If there's odd number of quotation marks, I'm inside a quoted string.
- Pre-split the line to parts that are inside and outside quotes and only format the outside parts.

Am I missing something obvious? Better alternatives?

Comment: I know that Eclipse and INtelliJ have Lua plugins. Perhaps you can use them to reformat your code base?

Comment: There's a cleaner alternative, but its lots more work.  Parse the LUA code into ASTs.  Regenerate the code from the ASTs.   If you do this, you're never confused about being in the middle of a string; by definition, that's a single tree node.  It also means you can use the structure of the code (e.g.,  IF ... ELSE IF ... ELSE IF ...) to format for special cases nicely.   If you don't want to go through this much trouble, you should get Astyle and hack it up for Lua.

Comment: One obvious thing you'll get into trouble with with the quote counting technique is escaped quotes as in this string: `"\""`.

Comment: @jpjacobs yes, it will be an endless path of corner cases. :( That's why I accepted silentbicycle's answer on implementing a real parser instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is usually called a 'pretty printer'.

Since Lua's [grammar](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#9) is so simple, the most robust approach would be to implement a parser for Lua syntax that just emits the parsed code in a standard style. You could hack this into the existing parser (lparser.c), or use one of the existing [grammars](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaGrammar) on the lua-users wiki. The grammar appears to be LL(1), so a simple recursive descent parser or LPEG would be good choices.

Trying to do this with *only* regular expressions almost always leads to more work than just using a real parser, as more and more special cases and contextual info (e.g. counting nested parentheses) creep into the regexes.

Comment: I'm afraid you are right, the regexp trickery seems a bit too Pandora's box :D Writing a syntax parser is something I haven't done but brings back memories from some university class..

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take is the following:

1. Replace all strings in the code with a numbered pattern, for example `$1$`, `$2$`, `$3$`... You of course keep in a table the original strings for each integer index.
2. Make whatever formatting you want (but be sure not to modify the patterns).
3. Replace back `$%n+$` patterns with the original string.